# fscanf return value for a string

Tags: c, scanf, return-value

Still new to coding and I'm really confused with this one. I searched up that fscanf returns the number of successfully assigned characters so why does the code below return 1 instead of 4?

```
string temp;
int len;

len = fscanf(fp, "%[^-,]s", temp);
printf("\n%s", temp);
printf("\nlen: %d", len);
temp[len] = '\0';
```

Output:

2020

len: 1

Comment: Is `string` type of `char*` or `char[]`?

Comment: I'm gonna downvote because this isn't an MRE as @RohanBari pointed out.

Comment: It is `printf()` function family which returns the length of the *output*.

Comment: Where did you read that `fscanf` returned a number of characters?  Either that was a *very* bad reference, or you didn't read it carefully enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I searched up that fscanf returns the number of successfully assigned characters

No. The `fscanf()` returns the number of successfully assigned **input items**.

From the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html) of `fscanf(3)`,

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the
> number of **successfully matched and assigned input items**; this
> number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure.

So, remember that `len = fscanf(...)` is not going to return the length of the characters that are correctly initialized, but the number of successfully assigned input items. In this case, it is 1 and that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> `len = fscanf(fp, "%[^-,]s", temp);`

- The [format specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Parameters) for an exclusion set `%[^-,]` does not require or include a trailing `s`.
- The return value of `fscanf` is the number of items assigned, not the character count.
- Also, `temp[len] = '\0';` is wrong here, and redundant in general.

The following shows how to correctly parse the first `-,` delimited token, with full error checking and using `%n` to retrieve the number of characters actually consumed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  const char str[] = "2021-02-12";

  char tok[79 + 1];                                // `%79s` or similar to prevent buffer overrun
  int len;                                         // number of characters actually parsed
  int cnt = sscanf(str, "%79[^-,]%n", tok, &len);  // number of items matched and assigned

  if(cnt != 1)
  {   printf("error reading token\n"); return 1; }

  printf("input: \"%s\"\n", str);
  printf("items: %d\n", cnt);
  printf("chars: %d\n", len);
  printf("token: \"%s\"\n", tok);
  printf("remaining: \"%s\"\n", str + len);

  return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/eocGGe):

```
input: "2021-02-12"
items: 1
chars: 4
token: "2021"
remaining: "-02-12"
```